# Concatenate, Merge or Combine 3 rows content into 1 row with OpenOffice

Tags: excel-formula, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have a xls document in OpenOffice with multiple rows, I want to concatenate strings from 3 lines and put into one

[image]

I know to concatenate columns is a little bit easyest, but how about rows

```
I want to merge three lines into one, result must to be like:
1 "I want to be merged"
2 "I also want to be merged"
```

result can be exported in the same or new sheet
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In D2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1;3)=1;A1&" "&B2&" "&C3;"")
```

If to move elsewhere, then select all, Copy and Paste Special check only 'Text'.